# AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction() Method not working sometimes

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am using an `AccessibilityService` in my app to paste some text in the `EditText` of another app.

I am using the following code to achieve the same,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_INT,
            AccessibilityNodeInfo.MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_WORD);
bundle.putBoolean(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_EXTEND_SELECTION_BOOLEAN,
            true);

eventSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY,
            bundle);

ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", stringToCopy);
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

eventSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

This works fine for normal cases. However, when I open up an `AlertDialog` from the `AccessibilityService` using

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

and execute the above code on dialog button press, it **behaves abnormally**.

**Case 1:** Works fine and text gets pasted from dialog

**Case 2:** Text gets pasted but selection is not made and therefore the previous word remains in the field

**Case 3:** Nothing happens, just the dialog dismisses.

However, in all cases the text is getting copied to **Clipboard** and can be pasted manually.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work, and this is how,

Initially I was calling, `Dialog.dismiss()` and `AccessibilityNodeInfo.performAction()` at the same time, which was causing a conflict as the `Window` was holding the view of the `Dialog` as the current active view and thus was not able to link to the `AccessibilityNode`.

I modified my code to this,

```
mDialog.dismiss();

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

     bundle.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_INT,
            AccessibilityNodeInfo.MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_WORD);
     bundle.putBoolean(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_EXTEND_SELECTION_BOOLEAN,
            true);

     eventSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY,
            bundle);

     ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
     ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", stringToCopy);
     clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

     eventSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
}, 300);
```

Now it works every time properly, after providing a delay in calling the `performAction()` and give enough time for the `Dialog` to dismiss completely.